# Calculate age from birth date

Tags: ios, swift

I can't find age in from birth date. What I got is

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

My code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
var dateString = user.birthday
        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        // this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        // voila!
        var dateFromString = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
        
        let age = calculateAge(dateFromString!)
}

func calculateAge (birthday: NSDate) -> NSInteger {
        
        var userAge : NSInteger = 0
        var calendar : NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        var unitFlags : NSCalendarUnit = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay
        var dateComponentNow : NSDateComponents = calendar.components(unitFlags, fromDate: NSDate())
        var dateComponentBirth : NSDateComponents = calendar.components(unitFlags, fromDate: birthday)
        
        if ( (dateComponentNow.month < dateComponentBirth.month) ||
            ((dateComponentNow.month == dateComponentBirth.month) && (dateComponentNow.day < dateComponentBirth.day))
            )
        {
            return dateComponentNow.year - dateComponentBirth.year - 1
        }
        else {
            return dateComponentNow.year - dateComponentBirth.year
        }
    }
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error? And what is the contents of dateString?

Comment: Most probably `let age = calculateAge(dateFromString!)` will be causing this issue. Its difficult to suggest a solution without knowing what `dateString ` contains

Answer (score 33, accepted):

update: **Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1**

You can use the Calendar method dateComponents to calculate how many years from a specific date to today:

```
extension Date {
    var age: Int { Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: self, to: Date()).year! }
}
```

---

```
let dob = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2000, month: 6, day: 30).date!
let age = dob.age // 19
```

[image]

Comment: How to achieve in Swift2 @SwiftArchitect ?

Comment: Why the DateComponents extension? It compiles (and runs) well (in Xcode 8 beta 4) without that, using the existing init method `public init(calendar: Calendar? = default, timeZone: TimeZone? = default, era: Int? = default, year: Int? = default, month: Int? = default, day: Int? = default, hour: Int? = default, minute: Int? = default, second: Int? = default, nanosecond: Int? = default, weekday: Int? = default, weekdayOrdinal: Int? = default, quarter: Int? = default, weekOfMonth: Int? = default, weekOfYear: Int? = default, yearForWeekOfYear: Int? = default)`

Answer (score 2):

**Important:**

The timezone must be set to create a UTC birth date otherwise there will be inconsistencies between timezones.

Swift 3

```
extension Date {

    //An integer representation of age from the date object (read-only).
    var age: Int {
        get {
            let now = Date()
            let calendar = Calendar.current

            let ageComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: self, to: now)
            let age = ageComponents.year!
            return age
        }
    }

    init(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
        var dc = DateComponents()
        dc.year = year
        dc.month = month
        dc.day = day

        var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!
        if let date = calendar.date(from: dc) {
            self.init(timeInterval: 0, since: date)
        } else {
            fatalError("Date component values were invalid.")
        }
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let dob = Date(year: 1975, month: 1, day: 1)
let age = dob.age

print(age)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2.0+ age computing code should look something like this:

```
extension NSDate {
    var age:Int {
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
            .components(NSCalendarUnit.Year, 
                        fromDate: self, 
                        toDate: NSDate(),
                        options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0)
            .year
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use the DateTools pod.  Absolutely the easiest way.
https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools

For Swift 3

```
import DateTools

let birthday: Date = ....
let ageString = String((Date() as NSDate).years(from: birthday))
```